# How to set background image to non-tiling in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, background, code-behind

Here is my code that i used to display an image in the background , but it is repeating and tiling . How do i do it in code behind to set the image to non-tiling ? i never use CSS to display the background image :

```
   protected void Image_Selection_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //PageBody.Attributes["bgColor"] = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value).Name;
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Ant and the Grasshopper")
        {
            PageBody.Attributes.Add("style", "background:url(images/ant-and-grasshopper.jpg);");
            PageBody.Attributes.Add("body", "background-repeat: no-repeat"); 
            Session["Background"] = "background:url(images/ant-and-grasshopper.jpg);";
            ImageButton9.Visible = false;
            ImageButton11.Visible = true;
        }

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Food Fit for the King")
        {
            PageBody.Attributes.Add("style", "background:no-repeat,background:url(images/King.jpg);");
            Session["Background"] = "background:url(images/King.jpg);";
            ImageButton11.Visible = false;
            ImageButton9.Visible = true;
        }

   }
```

i tried the background-repeat: no repeat but to no avail . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
"background:no-repeat,background:url(images/King.jpg);"
```

Ought to be

```
"background: url(images/King.jpg) no-repeat;"
```

Unless commas are treated specially, the comma between the two background attributes doesn't separate them. Only a semi-colon does that. Also, having two background attributes causes them to conflict.

Comment: What about stretch to fit screen?